# WPForms - Restrict Time options in date / time drop down

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My business uses the WPForms plugin for a reservation request form, for the most part it works great.  The problem I need to solve is that the date and time picker allow the user to select times (hours) when our store is actually closed.  How can I add javascript to restrict the hours to 7am - 10pm?  I tried tinkering with the examples on this page: https://developers.wpforms.com/docs/customize-the-date-time-field-date-picker/ but either there was no effect, or the page ended up breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with success - you need to install a plugin (like Code Snippets) to add PHP code to your wordpress and then you can paste there the code from the tutorial and apply the restriction like the following

```
...
// Limit times available to 7am - 10pm
minTime: '7:00am',
maxTime: '10:00pm'
...
```

. This should work ...